# How can I customize drf-yasg endpoints's example response?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

on my Django project, I'm using DRF and drf-yasg. At some endpoint, the example response body shows the incorrect example. like the following example:
[image]

But some of them don't show the correct example response body.[image]

This endpoint actually returns access_token and refresh_token, doesn't return the email and password. It's wrong information for the front-end devs. Is there any way to change this?

Comment: amongst the above 2 images which one is correct and which one is wrong response ? Also can you share the serializer and views for the respective endpoints

Comment: The first one is correct and they're both APIs of simple jwt. I didn't change anything on them. I actually want to customize swagger UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example using `@swagger_auto_schema` annotation with 3 serializers. 1 request serializer and 2 response serializers (success and error serializers).

```
class RequestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
   param = serializers.CharField()

                  
class SucessSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
   success = serializers.BooleanField()
   message = serializers.CharField()

                     
class ErrorSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
   success = serializers.BooleanField()
   errors = serializers.IntegerField()
```

---

```
class ExampleViewView(APIView):

    @swagger_auto_schema(
        request_body = RequestSerializer,
        responses={
            '200': SucessSerializer,
            '500': ErrorSerializer,
        },
        operation_description = 'Doc description'
    )
    def post(self, request):
        
        return successResponse({
            'sucess': True
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [drf-yasg docs](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/drf_yasg_integration.html). There is a way to make responses with jwt look properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).